# PDF-XChange Viewer Document Appearance Issues

Tags: pdf

What could be the cause for a .pdf file to not show properly? Texts do not fit into boxes, they are printed on top of each other and so on.

An example of the distortion using [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://tracker-software.com/):
[image]

Download this file [here](http://wiki.crypto.rub.de/Buch/download/Understanding-Cryptography-Chapter4.pdf).

How to fix this? Most other .pdf files I ever looked at showed properly but some, like this one, don't.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, ask over at tex.se.com, they have lots of experience not only with Tex but also with PS and PDF.

Comment: Does this happen in all PDF readers?

Comment: Is this a file you created?  If so, what font did you use?  What program did you use to create it?  Do other PDFs also look similar with the same viewer?

Comment: @Jan: It works fine in FoxitReader.
fixer1234: The producer is "GPL Ghostscript 8.64" and application is "dvips(k) 5.96dev Copyright 2007 Radical Eye Software". Note that I did not create this file myself, I got the information from the PDF properties.

Comment: I opened the file in Okular and it was fine.  Since several different PDF readers show the file correctly, it points to your viewer.  If PDF-XChange Viewer handles other PDFs correctly, it may be something like that viewer not handling this font well.  If many different PDFs have a problem, try the product support here: http://tracker-software.com/support

Comment: No issue with that file in the PDF viewer in FF32, I guess it's a viewer issue. Report this as a bug upstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I wasn't using the most up-to-date version.

Downloading the newest fixes the issue:
http://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads